# VS 2015 NuGet Versioning

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've recently created a number of NuGet packages and the versions follow the format x.x.x.x so every package has a default version of 1.0.0.0. This behaves as expected in VS 2013.

When I manage NuGet from VS 2015, looking at my IIS feed, I see the versions as 1.0.0 including the dependencies when in fact all versions are 1.0.0.0. Upon pulling packages in, everything seems to work correctly, but there is just this issue of version.

My concern is what will happen when I move to 1.0.0.1? I could update all my packages to follow the 3 digit format, but I'd obviously prefer to keep it as is. Seems like a strange bug.

How can I get VS 2015 to display the correct package version?

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: how are you creating those packages? (Ex. using assembly attributes from the dll, using a ,nuspec file, manually)

Comment: Manually through Nuget Package Explorer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the couple packages I've updated to 1.0.0.1 show the full version correctly.